# Youtube not playing in Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, youtube, video-streaming, onda-tablet

I have this real strange problem that youtube is not playing on my Onda Tablet (dark screen and "problem while playing"), when I am in my home wifi. When I use my mobile as a hotspot and connect my tablet to it (also via wifi) it's working. 
I use several android devices and the Onda Tablet is the only one, which does not play Youtube.
Other Video Players work without problems. This also happens, when I browse to m.youtube.com in a browser on the tablet.
Here's what I already tried:

- Clean Cache and data of youtube app
- reinstall youtube app
- manually downgrade youtube app
- changed DNS of the tablet to 8.8.8.8
- Factory reset the tablet
- Reset my router
  My only guess is a misconfiguration in the wifi options of the tablet but I could not find one.

My Tablet:
Onda air v989 running Android 4.4.4
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came across the solution for my very specific problem:

My tablet seems to have a problem concerning youtube and IPv6. It's probably some flaw in the firmware. 
After speaking to my internet provider I am now constantly leasing an IPv4 Adress and youtube is working just fine.

If you have similiar problems you should definitly try this out!